# solutions of system of linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Find values of $a$ and $b$ such that the system

$$
\begin{align}
a x - y &= 1 \\
x + b &= b
\end{align}
$$

has

1. exactly one solution
2. an infinite number of solutions
3. no solution

Comment: Is second equation is correct ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: The system (as shown at present) only has one solution. Period.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The matrix equation is:
$$
\underbrace{
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x \\
y 
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 \\
0 
\end{matrix}
\right)
}_{A u = v}
$$
What is $\mbox{det}\, A$ and what does it tell about the solutions of the system?